# spring: default parameter in controller pojo based on other service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin

i have a pojo

```
data class MyRequest(
        @field:DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
        val start: LocalDateTime,
        // ... other fields
)
```

and i want to use that pojo in a controller:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/api/v1/xxx")
    fun get(request: MyRequest) = ...
}
```

and now i would like to make `start` parameter optional and if missing set it to current value of `myFun()` from:

```
@Service
class MyService {
  fun myFun(): LocalDateTime = ...
}
```

does spring support it or i have to do it manually, changing pojo field to allowing `null`?

Comment: I'm guessing you tried changing the line to `val start: LocalDateTime = myService.myFun()` ? Is the problem that you don't have an static reference to `myFun()`?

Comment: @MatiasFuentes `myService` is a spring bean. so i don't have a static reference to the bean itself. also i would prefer to avoid static references as it's less testable this way